# Laravel 4.2 nested wherehas

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

As we are able to use nested in case of `with()`, similarly I need to use nested `whereHas` in **laravel version** **4.2**.

I tried...

```
->whereHas('children.childrenInfo' , function ($query) use ($search) {
    return $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
})
```

And also...

```
->whereHas('children' , function ($query) use ($search) {
    return $query->whereHas('childrenInfo' , function ($query) use ($search) {
        return $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    });
})
```

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: No I am not getting any error, Just an empty result.

Comment: can you show your all three models with relation function so i can help you

Comment: I think I am near to fix my problem. Above mentioned both queries are returning same result. So it means nested wherehas works. I think some where I am getting issue with parent and sub query same table name. In raw query which generated by above eloquent query if we place table alias it brings up result.